# OpenCSV does not write bean records

Tags: java, opencsv

I just start using OpenCSV for my project. After runing this code, created "test.csv" file on my Desktop but its empty. Where am i doing wrong?

```
public class test {
    List<MockBean> testData = new ArrayList<MockBean>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<MockBean> testData = new ArrayList<MockBean>();
            MockBean mb = new MockBean();
            mb.setName("kyle");
            mb.setOrderNumber("abc123456");
            mb.setNum(123);
            testData.add(mb);
            mb = new MockBean();
            mb.setName("jimmy");
            mb.setOrderNumber("def098765");
            mb.setNum(456);
            testData.add(mb);

            Writer writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\ali.gumusoglu\\Desktop\\New folder\\test.csv");

            ColumnPositionMappingStrategy mappingStrategy = 
                    new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
            mappingStrategy.setType(MockBean.class);

            StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<MockBean> builder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer);

            StatefulBeanToCsv beanWriter = builder
                    .withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy)
                    .withSeparator('#')
                    .withQuotechar('\'')
                    .build();
            beanWriter.write(testData);
            System.out.println("CSV File written successfully!!!");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to `close()` the file?

Comment: I tried now but it is not working.

Comment: Is there a folder called "New Folder" on your desktop?  FileWriter can only create a file it cannot create any directories.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the annotation to your bean class? 
For example,

```
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
private String name;
```

Comment: Yes, i tried this but not work. And i am starting to use Apache Poi. Thanks.

Comment: Have you alse tried the CsvBindByName annotation? I gave as example the position but I think the name is better. 
@CsvBindByName(column = "name")
Morevoer, could you give us more info about your bean. Does it extend any other class?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by implementing the getters methods in bean class.